# Update Embedded Mongo Documents - Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I've a model -

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    c_id = Integer()
    content = StringField()

class Page(DynamicDocument):
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

I insert the following data

```
comment1 = Comment(c_id=1,content='Good work!')
comment2 = Comment(c_id=2,content='Nice article!')
page = Page(comments=[comment1, comment2])
```

Now I want to update the comment whose id was `1` to `Great work!`. How can I do it?

I read on some SO thread that it can be done in following way:-

```
p_obj = Page.objects.get(comments__c_id=1).update(set__comments__S__content='Great work')
```

However, the above update throws an error saying:-

```
Update failed (Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.)
```

Following is the document structure:-

```
{
    "comments": [{
        "content": "Good Work",
        "c_id": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "content": "Nice article",
        "c_id": "2"
    }],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `Comment` model slightly. `c_id` field in the `Comment` model should be an mongoengine [`IntField()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.IntField) instead of `Integer()` you are using.

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    c_id = IntField() # use IntField here
    content = StringField()

class Page(DynamicDocument):
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

Secondly, When performing an `.update()` operation using `set`, you need to use [`.filter()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.base.datastructures.EmbeddedDocumentList.filter) instead of the `.get()` you are using as `.update()` will try to update documents.

**Updating embedded documents:**

We will try to update embedded documents in the Python shell. We will first import the models and then create 2 comment instances `comment1` and `comment2`. Then we create a `Product` instance and attach these comment instances to it.

To perform an update, we will first filter `Product` objects having `c_id` as `1` in the `comments` embedded document. After getting the filtered results we will call `update()` on it using `set__`.

**For example:**

```
In [1]: from my_app.models import Product, Comment # import models

In [2]: comment1 = Comment(c_id=1,content='Good work!') # create 1st comment instance

In [3]: comment2 = Comment(c_id=2,content='Nice article!') # create 2nd comment instance

In [4]: page = Page(comments=[comment1, comment2]) # attach coments to `Page` instance

In [5]: page.save() # save the page object
Out[5]: <Page: Page object>

# perform update operation 
In [6]: Page.objects.filter(comments__c_id=1).update(set__comments__S__content='Great work') 
Out[6]: 1 # Returns the no. of entries updated
```

**Check that value has updated:**

We can check that the value has updated by going inside the mongo shell and performing `.find()` on the `page_collection`.

```
> db.page_collection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5605aad6e8e4351af1191d3f"), "comments" : [ { "c_id" : 1, "content" : "Great work" }, { "c_id" : 2, "content" : "Nice article!" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. I got that working. Thanks a lot.  In the meantime, can you also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746083/mongo-embedded-document-query question. Thanks :)