# Mongo Embedded Document Query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I've 2 DynamicDocuments:

```
class Tasks(db.DynamicDocument):
    task_id = db.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.StringField()
    flag = db.IntField()

class UserTasks(db.DynamicDocument):
    user_id = db.ReferenceField('User')
    tasks = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Tasks'),default=list)
```

I want to filter the `UserTasks` document by checking whether the `flag` value (from Tasks Document) of the given task_id is `0` or `1`, given the task_id and user_id. So I query in the following way:-

```
obj = UserTasks.objects.get(user_id=user_id,tasks=task_id)
```

This fetches me an `UserTask` object.

Now I loop around the task list and first I get the equivalent task and then check its flag value in the following manner.

```
task_list = obj.tasks
for t in task_list:
    if t['task_id'] == task_id:
        print t['flag']
```

Is there any better/direct way of querying `UserTasks` Document in order to fetch the flag value of Tasks Document.

PS : I could have directly fetched flag value from the `Tasks` Document, but I also need to check whether the task is associated with the user or not. Hence I directly queried the `USerTasks` document.

Comment: Which version of mongoengine and pymongo you are using?

Comment: `pymongo==3.0.3`  and `mongoengine==0.10.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can we directly filter on a document with the [`ReferenceField's`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) fields in a single query?**

**No,** its not possible to directly filter a document with the fields of `ReferenceField` as doing this would require joins and mongodb does not support joins.

As per MongoDB docs on [database references:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)

> **MongoDB does not support joins.** In MongoDB some data is denormalized,
>   or stored with related data in documents to remove the need for joins.

From another [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/) on the official site:

> If we were using a relational database, we could perform a join on
>   users and stores, and get all our objects in a single query. **But
>   MongoDB does not support joins and so, at times, requires bit of
>   denormalization.**
>
> Relational purists may be feeling uneasy already, as if we were
>   violating some universal law. But let’s bear in mind that MongoDB
>   collections are not equivalent to relational tables; each serves a
>   unique design objective. A normalized table provides an atomic,
>   isolated chunk of data. A document, however, more closely represents
>   an object as a whole.

So in 1 query, we can't both filter `tasks` with a particular flag value and with the given `user_id` and `task_id` on the `UserTasks` model.

**How to perform the filtering then?**

To perform the filtering as per the required conditions, **we will need to perform 2 queries.**

In the first query we will try to filter the `Tasks` model with the given `task_id` and `flag`. Then, in the 2nd query, we will filter `UserTasks` model with the given `user_id` and the `task` retrieved from the first query.

**Example:**

Lets say we have a `user_id`, `task_id` and we need to check if the related task has `flag` value as `0`.

**1st Query**

We will first retrive the `my_task` with the given `task_id` and `flag` as  `0`.

```
my_task = Tasks.objects.get(task_id=task_id, flag=0) # 1st query
```

**2nd Query**

Then in the 2nd query, you need to filter on `UserTask` model with the given `user_id` and `my_task` object.

```
my_user_task = UserTasks.objects.get(user_id=user_id, tasks=my_task) # 2nd query
```

You should perform 2nd query only if you get a `my_task` object with the given `task_id` and `flag` value. Also, you will need to add error handling in case there are no matched objects.

**What if we have used `EmbeddedDocument` for the `Tasks` model?**

Lets say we have defined our `Tasks` document as an `EmbeddedDocument` and the `tasks` field in `UserTasks` model as an `EmbeddedDocumentField`, then to do the desired filtering we could have done something like below:

```
my_user_task = UserTasks.objects.get(user_id=user_id, tasks__task_id=task_id, tasks__flag=0)
```

**Getting the particular `my_task` from the list of tasks**

The above query will return a `UserTask` document which will contain all the `tasks`. We will then need to perform some sort of iteration to get the desired task.

For doing that, we can perform list comprehension using `enumerate()`. 
Then the desired index will be the 1st element of the 1-element list returned.

```
my_task_index = [i for i,v in enumerate(my_user_task.tasks) if v.flag==0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul for the explanation. I was really looking out for such an explanatory answer. Just one more question. Could I've perform the filtering  in one query if `Task` Model was an embedded Document? If yes, then how?

Comment: We could have done the filtering in a single query but it would return the whole `UserTasks` document containing all the `tasks`. You will have to perform some iteration to get to the desired task.

Answer (score 0):

@Praful, based on your schema you need two queries because mongodb does not have joins, so if you want to get "all the data" in one query you need a schema which fit that case.
ReferenceField is a special field which does a lazy load of the other collection (it requires a query).

Based on the query you need, I recommend you to change your schema to fit that. The idea behind NOSQL engines is "denormalization" so it is not bad to have a list of EmbeddedDocument. EmbeddedDocument can be a smaller document (denormalized version) with a set of fields instead of all of them.

If you do not want to load the whole document into memory while querying you can exclude that fields using a "projection".
Supossing your UserTasks has a list of EmbeddedDocument with the task you could do:

```
UserTasks.objects.exclude('tasks').filter(**filters)
```

I hope it helps you.

Good luck!

Comment: If, at all, I make `Tasks` model as `EmbeddedDocument` and `UserTasks` having list of EmbeddedDocument Tasks, then how would I get details of a particular task? ie for eg:- If I have a list of embedded Tasks and I want to find a task with `id=1`, I would query by `UserTasks.objects(tasks__task_id=1)`. It would still return me a `UserTask` object, wherein I have to still loop around the list of tasks which I was doing previously as well. How is it different or am I thinking in a wrong direction?

Comment: Can you give me an example which would solve my purpose in 1 query using embedded documents? Or even if I've to change the schema, what would be the suitable one in this case? Please provide an example. Thanks :)